# How to implement retry on failed connection for Firestore on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose while getting the data, the network connection is turned off and I got an error without getting any data:

```
Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

The method I used is:

```
mFirestoreDb.collection("somePath").document("anotherPath").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + documentSnapshot.getData());
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e);
        }
    });
```

How do I handle these type of errors so that when user clicks a retry button, it gets connected to Firestore and try to download the data again?

**Forgot to mention that I'm initializing Firestore within ViewModel Factory**. Now the problem is that if I initialize Firestore directly within Activity, then I can do a recursive call on a method, if I'm doing it right, but if I get the task from viewmodel, then I cannot do a recursive call like this:

On viewmodel class:

```
Task<DocumentSnapshot> task;

ViewModelConstructor(...) {
task = mFirestoreDb.collection("path")
                .document("anotherPath").get();
}

public Task<DocumentSnapshot> getTask() {
    return task;
}
```

On Activity:

```
private void someMethod() {
    // ... 
    viewModel.getTask().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e);
            someMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

P.S. I'm building an app for the first time and the only thing left is to implement a retry button.

Comment: Have you tried to wait until the user gets online again? Have you disabled offline persistence? I'm asking because Firestore has offline persistence enabled by default.

Comment: Offline persistent is turned on. And I think that recursive method of mine is/was all wrong. Just asking, don't you have any example video on handling errors? Any example would help on how to handle the errors.

Comment: About which recursive method ai you talking about?

Comment: I was trying to call the the same `OnSuccessListener`.

Comment: Which statement prints the following message `Failed to get document because the client is offline.`?

Comment: onFailure method. `OnCompleteListener` prints the full error though.

Comment: @AlexMamo Did some work and updated the question, see from "Forgot to mention that I'm initializing Firestore". Hope you can help...

Answer (score -1):

Following this official article: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices

"The Firestore SDKs and client libraries automatically retry failed transactions to deal with transient errors."